# strange overload = operator on some book, c-style?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I find some books which this kind of code:

[image]

but if I try to [compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35d7f0cde572c23b) somethings similar, it says that miss argument?

```
struct Test {
    double offsetDetected = 0.0;

    Test() {}
    Test &operator=() // removed here
};
```

what's wrong, and why books write this way those stuff? c-style?

Comment: The book is providing pseudo-code.   Pseudo-code looks something like code, but is not necessarily valid C++ code.   It's purpose is to demonstrate a concept and help understanding by a mere mortal.   It's purpose is not be to an example of actual code that a programmer might write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a binary operator.As the other asnwere mentioned it might have a typing error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    double offsetDetected = 0.0;

    Test() {}

    Test &operator=(const Test &obj); // removed here
};

int main() {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is C++, there's no "C style" for it. The book you're citing has a typo. That's all. I doubt that you find some "books". You found one book, I bet. The assignment operator requires an argument, since it's a binary operator.